# Recordings of Baer and Lewandowski

Tags: internet, chazzan-prayer-leader, music, recording, high-holidays

Chazzanim Avraham Baer z"l and Louis Lewandowski a"h created some of the most important books of chazzanut of the 19th century. [*בעל תפלה oder Der Praktische Vorbeter*](http://sammlungen.ub.uni-frankfurt.de/freimann/content/titleinfo/853537) and [*Kol Rinnah U'Tefillah*](http://petrucci.mus.auth.gr/imglnks/usimg/e/ef/IMSLP329506-PMLP533268-lewandowski_--_kol_rinnah_u_t_fillah.pdf) recorded for the first time, the oral traditions of the chazzanim of Western Europe. I have both, however my sight-reading is poor. Is there anyplace where I can find recordings of these nuschaot, in particular those of Baer, online?

I'm looking especially for niggunim for the Yomim Noraim (minchah, maariv, and Shabbat Shuvah).

Comment: Any luck tracking these down?

Comment: @DoubleAA, No, but I've found ones by other composers

Comment: This is an amazing post https://medium.com/@stuart.izon/melodies-of-rosh-hashana-yom-kippur-781e2dfb7987

Answer (score 2):

Wow! A Lewandowski fan, like me! I thought I'd never find one!

I learned and sang some of his compositions when I was part of the Yeshiva Univ. cantorial choir, years ago. I recommend that you contact the [Belz School of Jewish Music](http://www.yu.edu/belz/about/director/), as I'm quite certain that someone there may point you in the right direction. Cantor Bernard Beer is still directing it and is still there. I first had him as a music teacher when I went to MTA, then many years later as a Cantorial teacher when I took some school courses, there. He's an "icon" and a terrific person!

Cantor Malovanni still teaches there, also, and he would be another great knowledge source, if you can reach him. Sherwood Goffin, also, is there, occasionally - another reseource. Start with Cantor Beer.

BTW - if you want to hear some fascinating Baroque Cantorial music, research stuff by Salamone Rossi. Very different from what you may be used to hearing.

Comment: I LOVE Salamone Rossi. I love that epoque, the arrangement, everything about it. I have a CD from my father of the Zamir Chorale and Collegium Rossi singing his compositions both kodesh and chol.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - "Fair trade"?? I gave you an idea where you can find Lewandowski CDs. Where can I find Rossi CDs?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_14?url=search-alias%3Dpopular&field-keywords=salamone%20rossi&sprefix=salamone+rossi%2Caps%2C188 and http://berkshirerecordoutlet.com/search.php?row=0&brocode=&stocknum=&text=salamone+rossi&filter=all&cd=1&submit=Search

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - Thanks. IYH will check this after Shabbat. Shabbat Shalom and don't forget to sing, "Kol Haneshomah tehallel y-h" :-)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - See also, http://www.chazzanut.com/ I haven't investigated the entire site, but, judging from its content, I think you should be able to find some downlodable excerpts